# read my twitter account every 10 s

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I'm trying to read my twit (send with a smartphone) for a localhost application, twitter as remote…
I make a jquery+json script but with my crazy setInterval at 25ms, I find quickly the limit of 150 requests/hour, fail (like a whale)…
Do you know if the twitter API can help me to do more "read only" ?
Another option is to make my own twitter parser to extract from html (a tiny bot), but sound like stupid…

thank

Comment: if you make requests 40 times a second, they will think it is DOS attack

Comment: Authenticated requests are rate limited to 350 request per hour: *OAuth calls are permitted 350 requests per hour and are measured against the `oauth_token` used in the request.* Source: [The documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting). And why would you want to make a request every 25ms? You really have to lower the rate, there is no other possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch to twitter's streaming API which reverses the way that you get the data. Instead of you connecting to twitter and asking for the feed every 25ms you establish a connection to twitter and they will push the updates through that connection:

Detailed examples and documentation are here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/user-streams

This will get around the rate limits and make you local app very responsive.

Comment: Good :) but a little bit hard to understand with my basic english…
Can I do it with this lib :
[tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/blob/master/examples/sitestream.php) or have to find another example ?